# Terminate called after throwing an instance

Tags: c++

Привет, подскажите исправить runtime-error. Код можете увидеть здесь: http://ideone.com/Cv5rr2

```
int xA,yA, xB,yB;
int count = 0;
int n;
cin >> xA >> yA >> xB >> yB;
cin >> n;
int **Arr = new int* [3]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    Arr[i] = new int [n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        cin >> Arr[i][j];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((xA-Arr[i][0])*(xA-Arr[i][0])+(yA-Arr[i][1])*(yA-Arr[i][1]) <= (Arr[i][2]*Arr[i][2]) || (xB-Arr[i][0])*(xB-Arr[i][0])+(yB-Arr[i][1])*(yB-Arr[i][1]) <= (Arr[i][2]*Arr[i][2])) {
        count++;
    }
}

cout << count;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    delete [] Arr[n];
```

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: The requested URL /Cv5rr2. was not found on this server.
поправьте ссылку.

Comment: Сам исправил ошибку :)

Comment: Там просто "лишняя" точка в конце URL.

(я поправил)